# Where did the Delannoy numbers make their first appearance?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, combinatorics

I am writing a short exposition on the central Delannoy numbers and would like to find the year which Henri Delannoy first introduced them in a formal setting.

I *believe* Delannoy's initial presentation of the Delannoy numbers was through his article "Emploi de l'échiquier pour la résolution de certains problèmes de probabilités," which can be found on page 70 of [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=6CiVGxzVHW8C&pg=PA70&lpg=PA70&dq=%E2%80%99%20%CC%81echiquier%20pour%20lar%20%CC%81esolution%20de%20certains%20problemes%20de%20probabilite%20%CC%81es&source=bl&ots=KcvNXaEcip&sig=ACfU3U03otjL2j7BYyif2gqcPXNKyHkyWQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjHkviJ5e3nAhVGVs0KHWPjAYcQ6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%99%20%CC%81echiquier%20pour%20lar%20%CC%81esolution%20de%20certains%20problemes%20de%20probabilite%20%CC%81es&f=false) work. However, I cannot read French, and am unsure.

**My question:** Is this Delannoy's initial presentation of what are now called the Delannoy numbers?

Comment: The paper begins by referring to an earlier work from 1889 http://www-irem.univ-paris13.fr/site_spip/IMG/pdf/echiquiers_resolutions_certains_probabilites.pdf . Perhaps you have seen  *Why Delannoy numbers* https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0411128